# What's the word which means something that can be used in many different situations?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to think of this word for hours and it's really annoying me!

Comment: How about, *handy*, or maybe *multipurpose*?

Comment: Judging by your silence either it wasn't all that important or you've remembered what the word was.

Comment: An example sentence, or at least a part of speech, would be nice. Right now there are a multitude of possible answers.

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps thinking of something that is *versatile*, or *adaptable*?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

- *flexible*
- *multifunctional*